# QGIS Twisting a Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, georeferencing

I have a georeferenced raster in QGIS and a shapefile of the same area. Both files are in the same projection, but they do have different extents. For some reason on the left side the shapefile features have been shifted up and on the right, down. The shift is scaled from the center (center is lined up perfectly). Is there a way that I can twist my shapefile based the center point of the file, or a point that I pick? Or could I georeference my shapefile to my raster?

**Right Side**
[image: Right side]

**Left Side**
[image: Left side]

**Center**
[image: Center]

Comment: Affine plugin may help: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAffine/

Comment: Is this the same thing as the vector bending plugin?

Comment: The plugin is not in my version (3.10).

Comment: You have two options, downgrade your QGIS for the transformation or upgrade the plugin to QGIS 3.

Comment: Have you tried the Vector Bender plugin? Make sure the points you use are on opposite ends

Comment: @she_weeds What do you mean opposite ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select everything in edit mode and use the rotate tool in the Advanced Digitizing Toolbox but the rotation point will be fixed to the centre of the selection.

If you need a specified anchor point then use the Rotate tool under Vector Geometry>Rotate in the processing toolbox.

For more advanced vector geo-referencing the Vector Bender plugin (https://github.com/olivierdalang/VectorBender) works in v3 of QGIS - sounds like you already know of this one though?

Comment: I used vector bender, but my vector is not moving. I asked another question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Vector bender don't work for me, in QGIS 3.10.

I solved with SAGA Warping Shapes (acessible on processing painel). Its work well with Affine method.

http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/pj_georeference_2.html

Comment: I do not have the Affine plugin in my QGIS 3.10. Like it is not supported. That's why I had to go with Vector bender.